# FireFox - HTML5 Video works on my local not live site

Tags: html, firefox, video, html5-video

I am trying to show some videos on a website using HTML5. On my local copy the video work perfectly on every browser (ie...Chrome - Version 19.0.1084.56, Safari - 5.1.7  and FireFox - 13.0.1.) However, once I push the video to the live site FireFox seems to stop working. All I get is text stating, "No video and supported format and MIME type found." I have look all over the web and can't not seem to figure this out.

So far I have tried:

1.) Changing the order of the video sources(Moving FireFox video type to the top).

2.) I have reloaded the videos to the live website.

3.) Added the 'Codecs' to the file time. Nothing seems to work. Am I missing something? The only difference I can see is the live site is (https://). However that shouldn't matter. Any ideas or help would be awesome!

```
 <video width="685" height="451" controls  preload="none" poster="/video/office_safety.jpg" id="video">
      <source type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"' src="/video/office_safety.mp4" ></source>
      <source type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' src="/video/office_safety.ogv"></source>
      <source type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"' src="/video/office_safety.webm"></source>
    </video>
```

Comment: Did you set the mime types on the server ?

Comment: That is a good question. We host our own websites so I will have to ask. I didn't even think of that being a possibility.

Comment: That was the key to the city! Our htaccess file on the server did not have the correct MIME types. It works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you need to add mime types to htaccess file:

```
#AddType TYPE/SUBTYPE EXTENSION
AddType audio/mpeg mp3
AddType audio/mp4 m4a
AddType audio/ogg ogg
AddType audio/ogg oga
AddType audio/webm webma
AddType audio/wav wav

AddType video/mp4 mp4
AddType video/mp4 m4v
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType video/webm webm
AddType video/webm webmv
```